# Android- open from specific directory

Tags: java, android

I have specific path and I want open directory using this path. here is my code:

```
public void openFileDirectory(String path)
{
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    Uri uri;

    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state))
        uri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() +"/myApp/file");
    else
        uri = Uri.parse("/mnt/emmc/myApp/file");

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "*/*");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open folder")); 

}
```

after debugging, I figured out my path is something like :

*/storage/emulated/0/myApp/file/41242424212346436fsdf.pptx*

and I want to show :

*/storage/emulated/0/myApp/file/*

in depends of using external memory or internal memory.  but it open recent directory. 
I'm using galaxy s5 for debugging. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

You can use below code,

```
/* Path should be the complete path of the folder. */
    public void openDirectoryIntent(String path)
    {
        Uri selectedUri = Uri.parse(path);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(selectedUri, "resource/folder");
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

This method requires at least one folder explorer app installed on the device.
Example of use,

```
openDirectoryIntent(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/myApp/");
```